# How to pass parameters to error handler?

Tags: python, flask

In [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/errorpages/), there is:

```
from flask import render_template

@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
  return render_template('404.html'), 404
```

What is `e` and how do I pass a value to `page_not_found` to display?

My code is for a REST web service.  It `import abort`, and if a request for a resource results in the resource not available, I call `abort(404)`, as illustrated [here](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask) (about ¼ down). I would like to provide more information about the nature and circumstances of the 404 to the caller.

Comment: In this case `e` is the exception instance

Comment: It would help to know what you want to do. But maybe you can use [flashing features](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/flashing/)? You can flash an error and render the error template, and the flashed messages will show.

Comment: When the user gets a 404 page, the browser could have been redirected a few times and thus the address box wouldn't show the original url that eventually resulted in the 404. I would just like to produce some information so that the user can feed back to help trace the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

> What is `e`?

It is an Error response object. The documentation isn't clear what to do with it though, from [reading the API Spec](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.errorhandler)

> How do I pass a value to `page_not_found` to display

Just use the `render_template()` method like you would for any other page with values.

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(error):
    render_me = "Oh no! Page not found!"
    return render_template('404.html', message=render_me), 404
```

Where the `404.html` could simply be

```
<html>{{ message }}</html>
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question fully though. It answers `what is 'e'?` but not passing variables. 404 could be dynamic based on input in the URL, possibly. If you construct your flask URL as /<cascading>/<menu>/<thing>/and_this_ID_is_wrong, then you pass `cascading` and `menu` and `thing` in an @app.route you'd normally do `def method(pass, variables, here):` Could possibly render different  error templates based on the variables provided.

Comment: Maybe he wants to show "Event not found, search for another event?" rather than "Page not found," for example.

Comment: @ATLUS - I think I see what you are saying. A generic 404 page with a custom message based on the route. Makes sense now.

Comment: Thanks to all. ATLUS is correct about what I wanted to do. @cricket_007: Your updated example still looks static to me. How do I pass a value into the `page_not_found` method? I have imported `abort` and am calling abort(404).

Comment: @OldGeezer - Oh, you want a parameter to that method? Honestly, I think you would have to write a handler that would throw a 404 redirect to pass in the value to the `error` value, but I'm not well enough versed in Flask to know how to do that, sorry :/